# Generate PDF using PHP with Urdu text

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, mpdf

The Mpdf library claims that it can process UTF-8 characters but no matter what I try it's not working, even the examples given in the Mpdf manual are generating errors.

```
require_once  '../vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['allow_charset_conversion' => true]);

$html = '

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Document in Lithuanian</title>
</head>
<body>

... اسلام و علیکم  ...
لفظوں کا مجموعہ
</body>
</html>';



$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function after adding mpdf library

```
 private function generate_pdf($html, $title){
    error_reporting(0);
    $this->load->library('Mpdf');
    $mpdf = new Mpdf('ar','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
    $mpdf->SetFont("Jameel Noori Nastaleeq");
    $mpdf->setTitle($title);
      // $mpdf->SetDirectionality('ltr');
    $mpdf->mirrorMargins = true;
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
  }
```